# Determining the Appropriate Trendline and Statistical Test for Sleep and Muscle Mass Data

Tags: regression, correlation, trend

I am currently working on a dataset that explores the relationship between the amount of sleep (in hours) and the change in muscle mass (in kilograms). I have collected data and plotted it on a scatter plot, but I am uncertain whether a linear or polynomial trendline would be more appropriate for this data.

Here is the scatter plot for reference (x-axis is hours of sleep, y-axis is change in muscle mass):
[image: Graph for data]

The scatter plot doesn't make it immediately clear whether the relationship is linear or if there's a curve that would suggest a polynomial trendline would be more appropriate. The data seems to suggest that there might be a non-linear relationship, but I'm not entirely sure.

In Excel, a 4th to 6th degree polynomial seem to fit the data points, but considering this is for a high school research paper, I don't know if showing a 6th degree polynomial equation is overkill or not.

I would greatly appreciate it if you could provide guidance on:

- How to determine if a linear or polynomial trendline is more suitable for this data.
- The statistical tests that I should consider applying to ascertain the strength and nature of the relationship.

Upon request I have added a graph that has all the points of the 10 repetitions of each level of sleep plotted.

[image: Graph 2]

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! I have many thoughts on this, but most or all of them hinge on your answer to this: why do you have intervals around your plotted points? For instance, do you have many measurements at each sleep value that you've summarized into an average? If so, what does that interval mean, a confidence interval for the mean? The interquartile range of the original data? (There is a huge difference between the interval being about the mean or about the original data.) $//$ Would it be possible to post a plot of all of the points, not just the averages?

Comment: @Dave The original research is from a simulation for a range of hours of sleep (2h-10h with 1h increments), 10 repetitions were done  for each level of sleep where the difference (final mass - initial mass) was calculated. I have now edited the original question and provided upon your request the graph showing all plotted points, notice that they are so close together you can't really tell a difference.

Comment: What do you mean that there were ten "repetitions" at each sleep duration? Were there $90$ subjects involved in this study? Were there ten, each of whom got measured at each sleep duration?

Comment: By repetitions, I mean replicas of the same parameters. Seeing as the investigation was conducted with a simulator, where the only variable that was changed through different iterations was hours of sleep of the individual, what I mean with a repetition/replica is the act of running more than once the simulator with the exact same set of parameters, since even by having the same parameters the final result of change in muscle mass differs a little. I am unsure if this clears it up

Comment: What exactly is the simulation doing? Is it simulating ninety distinct subjects? One subject measured ten times with two hours of sleep, another measured ten times with three hours of sleep, etc? Ten subjects, each of whom sleep two hours, then three, then four, etc?

Comment: It does not seem to specify, not even providing real units for its numbers (I had to develop a factor of conversion). Seeing as their initial muscle mass varies slightly between iterations, we can assume them to be different subjects but with very similar characteristics (in terms of age, gender...), but as I said it is very simplistic. You simply run the simulation at the desired hours of sleep (while keeping days between workouts, duration of the simulation, intensity of exercise and percent of slow twitch fibers constant) and do a simple substraction to find the chang

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150449/discussion-between-miles-jarra-gloekler-and-dave).